# Front-end doesn’t fetch backend. AWS, Heroku

Tags: java, angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, frontend

I built a web app in VS Code using Java, Angular, and Spring Boot. My code runs well locally, but when you deploy it to AWS or Heroku something interesting happens. The backend sends the output to /api/articles and a JSON shows up here yet the front end is not fetching it for some reason. Now, interesting enough after a minute or two the articles show up in the front end but only in my machine. I want to make this part clear: it works from aws and heroku servers but so far only when I access it from my pc, not even my phone or a friends laptop. I am completely clueless.

Comment: Have you looked at the REST requests your frontend app is making to the backend in your browser developer tools to confirm they are going where you expect? Is the backend actually getting called? What is it returning? Are there any errors?

Comment: The backend is getting called. I can see the request results in the api/ path so yes. The backend seems to be working fine.

Comment: And it is working fine locally, so it might be that the fetch requests in my front end are getting blocked, somehow

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I am developing API endpoints for a new service, I will run into similar issues when I am not setting CORS correctly.
To make an AJAX call from the browser to a server the server must return an header to inform the browser the domain is allowed to call this server.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: For some reason I had the suspicion that it was related to this. So i included the @Cross Origin annotation in my java controllers, is that not enough?

Comment: You’d need to inspect the HTTP traffic. If it doesn’t have the header or if the header doesn’t allow the origin you are making the request from then it may need some additional configuration. I am not familiar with Spring but I’ve built many APIs with many languages and this is a common stumbling block.

Comment: I use a program called Fiddler to proxy the HTTP traffic through so I can see and debug these types of things.

Comment: Could it be related to me calling http instead of https?

Comment: error: GET http://localhost:5000/api/articles net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
m @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
f @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1
O.s.<computed> @ polyfills.2e71067f259e79e852da.js:1

Comment: am getting that error when front end tries to reach the backend

Comment: Yes if when deployed, it’s being served as https and you are trying to get the data with http that would cause issue too.

Comment: If you are getting a CORS error you will see it in the dev tools Console in Chrome. Does anything appear there when your app makes an api call?

Comment: Can you share what you added for the @CrossOrigin annotation? You need to include where you are allowing requests from. If your app is deployed to myexampleapp.com then this is what you'd include as the allowed origin. To call the backend when deployed to the cloud but called from running your frontend locally for testing would also require adding localhost as an origin. This should be useful https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/